# How does the U.S. States Department select Immigration Diversity Lottery winners exactly?

Tags: united-states, immigration

From what I've read, it seems that they select a random sample of 50,000 - 55,000 winners from the pool of applicants worldwide. But from the statistics I've seen, the distribution is not uniformly random. My next guess is that they select a random sample of 50,000 - 55,000 winners, and then apply rejection sampling so that no country has more than 7% winners. My guess is probably not correct. What is the precise algorithm/procedure the U.S. States Department uses to arrive at the final selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every year the U.S States Department randomly selected 50,000
> applicants for the Green Visa lottery program. All applicants are
> selected randomly as a whole, for the number of visas allocated for
> that region, but with the limitation that no single country may
> receive more than 7% of the total diversity visas. That is the maximum
> number of applicants per country that can get a green visa is not more
> than 3,500.

([Source](https://www.ivisa.com/usa-blog/green-card-lottery-how-many-per-country))